# Property of fixed-point free permutations of an infinite set

Tags: permutations, infinity

I'm curious if the following property always holds.
Let $f:X\rightarrow X$ be a bijection from an infinite set $X$ into itself, such that for all $x\in X$ it holds that $f(x)\neq x$. Then there exists some subset $A\subseteq X$ such that $$X=A\sqcup f(A). $$
Where $\sqcup$ means that the union is disjoint.

A simple example of this property is provided by the map $f:\mathbb{Z}\rightarrow\mathbb{Z}:n\mapsto n+1$, where the corresponding subset of $X=\mathbb{Z}$ is $A=2\mathbb{Z}$.

Is this property always true? Can someone provide a counter-example?

Comment: Bijections always have a cycle decomposition even on an infinite set so you can answer questions about them using that. Your condition is equivalent to the condition that every cycle has even length, where infinite cycles count as even.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No. Odd cycles are your enemy.

Take $X=S^1$ and $f(z)=e^{\frac 23\pi i}z$. Then $f(f(f(x)))=x$ for all $x$ and you have problems assigning $x,f(x),f(f(x))$ to $A$ without conflicts.

Smaller counterexample: $X=\Bbb Z$ and
$$ f(x)=\begin{cases}x+1&x\in\{-1,0\}\\-x&\text{otherwise}\end{cases}$$